# React useState not rerendering

Tags: reactjs

I am currently implementing a drag and drop system, in one of my js file I have implemented a functional component using React hooks, I have been working with class components, and I am not very familiar with the functional component of React.

So I know in class component, `this.setState` will re-render, however, when I use setState in functional component it does not re-render the component.

Here is my code

```
// My state declaration
const [items, setItems] = React.useState({
  row1: [],
  row2: [],
  row3: []
});

...
// This is my setItems call
setItems(prevState => {
  let tempHolder = items;
  // itemArray is a value passed down as props
  tempHold.row1 = itemArray;
  return tempObj;
});
```

I know that the problem causing this to happen is that React thinks my return value is the same as `items`, so it did not cause `setItems` to re-render, but I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo in the example, but the code calls `setVideos`, but should be `setItems`.

Comment: Yea had a typo there, fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the expression you return from the setter function is not `===` to the expression currently in state:

```
const [items, setItems] = React.useState({
  row1: [],
  row2: [],
  row3: []
});
// ...
setItems({
  ...items,
  row1: itemArray
});
```

(since the setter function is named `setItems`, that's the function name you should call - *not* `setVideos`)

Whether in class components or in functional components, don't mutate state - create new objects instead.

In this case, you might also consider having separate state variables, eg:

```
const [row1, setRow1] = useState([]);
```

and then you just have to call `setRow1` without messing with any of the other rows.

If you have lots of rows, I think an array of arrays in state would make more sense:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(() => Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => []));
// ...
setItems(items.map(
  (item, i) => i === 0 ? itemArray : item
));
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, this helps a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh oops, it was a typo, sorry. And thanks a lot for the suggestion